# java package in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, package

I am using netbeans6.7 ide.
I have created a jsp file usermanagement.jsp in jspfiles folder in web folder

and created a java package com.test.test1 then created a java class in temp in this java package.

Now I want to import this java package in usermanagement.jsp
I have written

```
<%@ page import=''%>
```

but my package is not getting populated there.

What should I do?

Do I have to write something in web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

The 'page import' section get populated automatically the moment you use a class.

The way to get it to auto-populate the 'import' directive is to start typing the fully qualified name of your class and hitting Ctrl-Space
e.g Try typing com.test.test1.Temp followed by Ctrl-Space.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans should know where to look for class files.Right click on your project and select 'properties' and there should be an option to select the folder where you have the class files.(Don't remember right now)